New data set from “For loop”
I'm a complete beginner in “R” and am currently getting by with tutorials and videos from the Internet. At the moment I'm still doing all my statistical tasks with Excel (or Libreoffice) ... but that's too stupid for me in the long run - for license reasons alone - especially as I've been a Linux user for decades.
My problem:
I create a csv file from a database with calculated mean values of a query. This file is drawn for a calendar year and therefore contains completely zero values in some lines. (Event has not yet taken place).
The Dataset: ("Beispiel.csv")
Merkmal;Kriterium 1;Kriterium 2;Kriterium 3;Kriterium 4;Gesamt
251;0;0;0;0;0
251;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
254;0;0;0;0;0
608;0;0;0;0;0
600;0;0;0;0;0
602;0;0;0;0;0
253;0;0;0;0;0
253;0;0;0;0;0
609;0;0;0;0;0
265;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
601;0;0;0;0;0
604;0;0;0;0;0
222;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
604;0;0;0;0;0
289;0;0;0;0;0
278;0;0;0;0;0
308;0;0;0;0;0
266;0;0;0;0;0
299;0;0;0;0;0
602;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
805;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
224;0;0;0;0;0
427;0;0;0;0;0
309;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
275;0;0;0;0;0
600;0;0;0;0;0
607;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
309;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
430;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
608;0;0;0;0;0
321;0;0;0;0;0
317;0;0;0;0;0
163;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
600;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
805;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
230;0;0;0;0;0
290;0;0;0;0;0
606;0;0;0;0;0
601;0;0;0;0;0
299;0;0;0;0;0
276;0;0;0;0;0
310;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
302;0;0;0;0;0
604;0;0;0;0;0
320;0;0;0;0;0
222;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
608;0;0;0;0;0
275;0;0;0;0;0
289;0;0;0;0;0
433;0;0;0;0;0
180;0;0;0;0;0
180;0;0;0;0;0
250;0;0;0;0;0
602;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
603;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
435;1,69;1,62;2;1,33;1,77
997;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
268;1,8;1,67;2;1,2;1,82
609;1,38;1,13;1,38;1,25;1,3
310;1,53;1,53;1,59;1,35;1,55
996;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
321;1,27;1,53;1,27;1;1,36
601;1,88;1,63;1,63;1,25;1,71
320;1,19;1,06;1,31;1,13;1,19
996;0;0;0;0;0
157;1,5;1,75;1,69;1,53;1,65
996;0;0;0;0;0
229;1,25;1,25;1,25;1,31;1,25
322;1,45;1,27;1,27;1,09;1,33
996;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
257;0;0;0;0;0
600;1,73;1,8;1,4;1,53;1,64
604;1,12;1,12;1,47;1,12;1,24
996;0;0;0;0;0
256;0;0;0;0;0
320;1,44;1,28;1,61;1,39;1,44
997;0;0;0;0;0
320;1,38;1,38;1,63;1,36;1,46
601;1,59;1,59;1,82;1,35;1,67
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
603;2,2;1,8;2,4;1,4;2,13
225;1,47;1,67;1,8;1,27;1,65
231;2;2;1,77;1,54;1,92
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
299;1,6;1,73;1,87;1,87;1,73
602;1,25;1,08;1,17;1,33;1,17
604;2,24;1,82;2,12;1,12;2,06
996;0;0;0;0;0
606;1,14;1,07;1,21;1;1,14
126;1,5;1,38;1,5;1,25;1,46
319;1,33;2,11;1,67;1,11;1,7
605;1,78;1,67;1,89;1,11;1,78
320;1,44;1,5;1,81;1,5;1,58
265;1,47;1,59;1,53;1,47;1,53
997;0;0;0;0;0
600;1,47;1,41;1,81;1,24;1,56
158;2,27;2,07;2,29;1,33;2,21
320;1,53;1,12;1,82;1,18;1,49
320;1,08;1;1,23;1,23;1,1
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
276;1,06;1,06;1,35;1,35;1,16
996;0;0;0;0;0
607;2,31;1,92;2,31;1,46;2,18
317;2,31;2,63;2,81;1,63;2,58
224;1,94;1,88;1,5;1,5;1,77
996;0;0;0;0;0
608;4,27;2,73;4,18;1,42;3,73
996;0;0;0;0;0
289;1,6;1,4;1,67;1,47;1,56
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
259;0;0;0;0;0
433;1,31;1,19;1,5;1,25;1,33
163;1,53;1,8;1,73;1,07;1,69
600;1,72;1,67;1,61;1,39;1,67
997;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
222;1,65;1,82;1,88;1,19;1,78
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
609;1,27;1,2;1,53;1,07;1,33
320;1,39;1,11;1,39;1,33;1,3
223;1,73;1,27;1,64;1;1,55
308;2,33;2,83;2,17;1,39;2,44
996;0;0;0;0;0
266;2,09;1,64;1,64;1,18;1,79
997;0;0;0;0;0
322;1,13;1,13;1,19;1;1,15
603;2,07;1,8;2,27;1,47;2,05
601;1,53;1,24;1,35;1,18;1,37
996;0;0;0;0;0
602;2,29;2,47;2,35;1,69;2,37
321;1,06;1,19;1,13;1;1,13
996;0;0;0;0;0
603;3,33;2,73;3,47;2,07;3,18
606;1,2;1,2;1,2;1;1,2
321;1,06;1;1,25;1;1,1
320;1,41;1,35;1,65;1,41;1,47
289;1,54;1,46;1,38;1,69;1,46
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
275;1,85;1,85;1,69;1,31;1,8
608;2,86;2;2,79;1,79;2,55
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
320;1,17;1,06;1,5;1,61;1,24
320;1,36;1,21;1,57;1,21;1,38
320;1,35;1,41;1,41;1,06;1,39
322;1,35;1,12;1,47;1;1,31
436;2,57;2,14;2,5;2,29;2,4
997;0;0;0;0;0
609;1,58;1,5;2,17;1,58;1,75
414;1,39;1,44;1,5;1,61;1,44
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
601;1,33;1,33;1,47;1,27;1,38
428;1,33;1,17;1,83;1;1,44
997;1,38;1,5;1,5;2,13;1,46
320;1,06;1,06;1,17;1,06;1,1
997;0;0;0;0;0
308;1,36;1,73;1,55;1;1,55
320;1,22;1,11;1,11;1,25;1,15
997;0;0;0;0;0
605;1,53;1,33;1,47;1,33;1,44
253;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
600;1,33;1,17;1,39;1,39;1,3
607;1,44;1,5;1,69;1,31;1,54
996;0;0;0;0;0
263;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
299;1,53;1,47;1,41;1,47;1,47
603;2,27;2,07;1,93;1,47;2,09
320;1,41;1,47;1,41;1,06;1,43
320;1,28;1,11;1,67;1,11;1,35
219;1,72;1,72;1,94;1,44;1,79
320;1,28;1,29;1,56;1,06;1,38
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
435;1,82;1,24;2,07;1,25;1,71
230;1,59;1,71;1,71;1,06;1,67
163;1,56;1,56;1,44;1,38;1,52
996;0;0;0;0;0
608;4,2;2,53;3,67;1,4;3,47
320;1,44;1,56;1,56;1,39;1,52
996;0;0;0;0;0
289;1,4;1,27;1,6;1,13;1,42
609;1,18;1;1,45;1,45;1,21
996;0;0;0;0;0
602;2,31;2,81;2,63;1,2;2,58
224;1,47;1,71;1,47;1,18;1,55
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
600;1,38;1,5;1,38;1,38;1,42
996;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
320;1,44;1,39;1,67;1,61;1,5
310;1,39;1,56;1,39;1,22;1,45
320;1,33;1,11;1,25;1,17;1,23
320;1,47;1,29;1,41;1,41;1,39
603;2,95;1,74;3,72;1,05;2,8
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
302;1,38;1,31;1,38;1,15;1,36
601;1,89;1,72;1,76;1,72;1,79
996;0;0;0;0;0
605;1,47;1,73;1,93;1,07;1,71
996;0;0;0;0;0
317;1,65;2;1,93;1,35;1,86
320;1,25;1,19;1,31;1,69;1,25
433;1,38;1,23;1,31;1,08;1,31
603;3,24;2,82;2,71;1,13;2,92
996;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
996;0;0;0;0;0
229;1,5;2,36;1,93;1,36;1,93
259;0;0;0;0;0
320;1,18;1;1,12;1,06;1,1
320;1,22;1,06;1,33;1,28;1,2
251;0;0;0;0;0
997;0;0;0;0;0
320;1,35;1,29;1,44;1,12;1,36
996;0;0;0;0;0


(I have removed all unimportant columns from the example file, shortened the number of rows (there are otherwise 10 times as many and changes ... as mentioned above) and renamed the columns (for data protection reasons). The “characteristic” normally still has an individual identifier, but I have already managed to do this here with the function:
beispiel$merkmal <- substr(beispiel$merkmal, 1, 3)

... to the three characters on the left. )
Depending on the characteristic in column 1, I would now like to calculate the mean value for each criterion depending on each characteristic. In principle, this means that a function deletes all rows that have a zero value in all criteria, as they would distort the value when calculating the mean value.
I then want to determine the mean value - e.g. of the characteristic “320” - for each of the four criteria across the entire table and write it into a new dataframe.
In other words, a dataframe is to be created that contains the characteristic only once in the first column and the mean values for the 4 characteristics in each of the following 4 columns.
This dataframe should then be the output for a barplot ... rather 4 barplots.

I would now like to add a minimal example, but I don't even know how to start. I don't want any of you to write the script for me, but to give me a push in the right direction.
I would like to do all the steps in R - as far as possible - and not “prepare” the table in Libreoffice first.

how can I delete the rows that contain zero values in all columns (criteria 1 - 4)?

how can I calculate the individual mean values (my idea would be with a “for loop”)?


Thanks in advance
Stefan
(How do I upload the sample file?)

First use read.csv, with your own sep argument. Then sub the , to . per column using sapply. Finally cast to data.frame and aggregate on Merkmal with FUN=sum.

To filter all zero rows do something like df[!rowSums(df[,2:6]) == 0,]

First, read the semicolon-separated file using read.csv.
Then, replace the comma, since that is a string also cast to numeric with as.numeric(sub ...
Get a data.frame and finally assign it.
df <- data.frame(sapply(read.csv("Beispiel.csv", sep=";"), \(x) 
                   as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x))))

Doing the calculation by grouping variable Merkmal with aggregate on the filtered data set.
aggregate(. ~ Merkmal, df[!rowSums(df[,2:6]) == 0,], FUN=mean)

output
   Merkmal Kriterium.1 Kriterium.2 Kriterium.3 Kriterium.4   Gesamt
1      126    1.500000    1.380000    1.500000    1.250000 1.460000
2      157    1.500000    1.750000    1.690000    1.530000 1.650000
3      158    2.270000    2.070000    2.290000    1.330000 2.210000
4      163    1.545000    1.680000    1.585000    1.225000 1.605000
5      219    1.720000    1.720000    1.940000    1.440000 1.790000
6      222    1.650000    1.820000    1.880000    1.190000 1.780000
7      223    1.730000    1.270000    1.640000    1.000000 1.550000
8      224    1.705000    1.795000    1.485000    1.340000 1.660000
9      225    1.470000    1.670000    1.800000    1.270000 1.650000
10     229    1.375000    1.805000    1.590000    1.335000 1.590000
11     230    1.590000    1.710000    1.710000    1.060000 1.670000
12     231    2.000000    2.000000    1.770000    1.540000 1.920000
13     265    1.470000    1.590000    1.530000    1.470000 1.530000
14     266    2.090000    1.640000    1.640000    1.180000 1.790000
15     268    1.800000    1.670000    2.000000    1.200000 1.820000
16     275    1.850000    1.850000    1.690000    1.310000 1.800000
17     276    1.060000    1.060000    1.350000    1.350000 1.160000
18     289    1.513333    1.376667    1.550000    1.430000 1.480000
19     299    1.565000    1.600000    1.640000    1.670000 1.600000
20     302    1.380000    1.310000    1.380000    1.150000 1.360000
21     308    1.845000    2.280000    1.860000    1.195000 1.995000
22     310    1.460000    1.545000    1.490000    1.285000 1.500000
23     317    1.980000    2.315000    2.370000    1.490000 2.220000
24     319    1.330000    2.110000    1.670000    1.110000 1.700000
25     320    1.319583    1.225417    1.455833    1.278333 1.333333
26     321    1.130000    1.240000    1.216667    1.000000 1.196667
27     322    1.310000    1.173333    1.310000    1.030000 1.263333
28     414    1.390000    1.440000    1.500000    1.610000 1.440000
29     428    1.330000    1.170000    1.830000    1.000000 1.440000
30     433    1.345000    1.210000    1.405000    1.165000 1.320000
31     435    1.755000    1.430000    2.035000    1.290000 1.740000
32     436    2.570000    2.140000    2.500000    2.290000 2.400000
33     600    1.526000    1.510000    1.518000    1.386000 1.518000
34     601    1.644000    1.502000    1.606000    1.354000 1.584000
35     602    1.950000    2.120000    2.050000    1.406667 2.040000
36     603    2.676667    2.160000    2.750000    1.431667 2.528333
37     604    1.680000    1.470000    1.795000    1.120000 1.650000
38     605    1.593333    1.576667    1.763333    1.170000 1.643333
39     606    1.170000    1.135000    1.205000    1.000000 1.170000
40     607    1.875000    1.710000    2.000000    1.385000 1.860000
41     608    3.776667    2.420000    3.546667    1.536667 3.250000
42     609    1.352500    1.207500    1.632500    1.337500 1.397500
43     997    1.380000    1.500000    1.500000    2.130000 1.460000


Would dec = "," not work here to avoid replacing "," to "."?

@gabagool Yes, should work here. I just find it a bit unreliable at times, especially when you have mixed representations of both, comma and dot. It then fails on the whole column, or you have to scan each value separately. But sure, if you have it exclusively it works fine.

it's usually more helpful if you provide some sample data via dput(). For example, here I'm taking the first 2 rows of the mtcars dataset:
dput(head(mtcars, 2))

Then, your console will display:
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6), disp = c(
    160,
    160
), hp = c(110, 110), drat = c(3.9, 3.9), wt = c(2.62, 2.875), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02), vs = c(0, 0), am = c(1, 1), gear = c(
    4,
    4
), carb = c(4, 4)), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame")

Now, any potential answerer can copy and paste that into their R session and have the same data you're working with. Alternatively, you can provide a data.frame via code so others can produce, which is what I've done below.
# example data
df <- data.frame(
    M = c(180, 268, 609, 268, 609),
    K1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
    K2 = c(69, 0, 28, 0, 54),
    K3 = c(1.62, 0, 1.67, 0, 1.72),
    K4 = c(2, 0, 2, 0, 2),
    K5 = c(1.33, 0, 1.2, 0, 1.6),
    G = c(1.77, 0, 1.88, 0, 1.45)
)

I believe this looks similar to what you're working with.
       M    K1    K2    K3    K4    K5     G
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:   180     1    69  1.62     2  1.33  1.77
2:   268     0     0  0.00     0  0.00  0.00
3:   609     1    28  1.67     2  1.20  1.88
4:   268     0     0  0.00     0  0.00  0.00
5:   268     1    54  1.72     2  1.60  1.45

Anyway, I like the data.table package for these kind of things. Once you install the data.table package, you can cast a data.frame into a data.table and then take these summaries.
# cast to data.table
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(df)

# take the means of the columns, by the Merkmal column
# excluding Merkmal == 268
dt[!M %in% c(268), lapply(.SD, mean), by = M, .SDcols = c("K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", "G")]

Here I've commented what each part of that does:
dt[
    # filter out the Merkmals you don't want
    !M %in% c(268),
    # this says to apply the mean() function over the columns listed in .SDcols, 
    lapply(.SD, mean),
    # do this operation separately for each Merkmal
    by = M,
    # the columns to take the mean of
    .SDcols = c("K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", "G")
]

You could also filter by the values in K1.
df[K1 != 0, lapply(.SD, mean), by = M, .SDcols = c("K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", "G")]

In either case, this results in:
       M    K1    K2    K3    K4    K5     G
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:   180     1    69 1.620     2  1.33 1.770
2:   609     1    41 1.695     2  1.40 1.665

Cheers and welcome to SO!

As much as I like (love) data.table, I wouldn't recommend to start learning R with it. Same applies to dplyr btw. base R can do everything one can wish for and more, data.table even relies on some principles from it (like lapply within j), but also complicates things for beginners by introducing its own specific syntax constructs that do not work in base.
